# What is the best way to save Formik values in Redux Toolkit so that I can persist them with redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, formik

I have a multi step form made in React with formik and I am also using Redux Toolkit with redux-persist. I am able to save the form steps in the Redux state and the user remains in the current step even if they close/open the window again. But how can I also store the formik values he has entered in the Redux state so that the values persist as well?

This is the code of my form:

```
export default function UserDetailsForm() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: FormInitialValues,
    validationSchema: FORM_MODULES[module]?.schema[formStep],
    onSubmit: (values, actions) => {
      sendFormRequest(values, actions);
    },
  });

  return (
        <form className='form-container' onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>


          {/* 1. Personal Info */}

          {module === 0 &&
          <PersonalInfo
            formik={formik}
            formStep={formStep}
            setFormStep={handleSetFormStep}
          />}

          {/* 2. Additional Info */}

          {module === 1 &&
          <AdditionalInfo
            formik={formik}
            formStep={formStep}
            setModule={handleSetModule}
            setFormStep={handleSetFormStep}
          />}

          {/* 3. Job Info */}

          {module === 2 &&
          <JobInfo
            formik={formik}
            formStep={formStep}
            setModule={handleSetModule}
            setFormStep={handleSetFormStep}
          />}

          {/* 4. Product Info */}

          {module === 3 &&
          <ProductInfo
            formik={formik}
            formStep={formStep}
            setModule={handleSetModule}
            setFormStep={handleSetFormStep}
            isSubmitting={isSubmitting}
          />}

        </form>
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a state slice for your draft values then you can watch values changes returned from useFormik hooks and trigger an action to save them.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(saveDraftValues(formik.values)) 
}, [formik.values])
```

You can add the ***step*** as dependency to save the draft values only when a step is finished to avoid triggering multiple action on form changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(saveDraftValues(formik.values)) 
}, [step])
```

Then you can get the value from the store, for instance **formDraft**  slice and if it's not null set your initial values with the draft values

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const formDraft = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.formDraft.value);
const formik = useFormik({
 initialValues: formDraft || FormInitialValues,
 validationSchema: FORM_MODULES[module]?.schema[formStep],
 onSubmit: (values, actions) => {
   sendFormRequest(values, actions);
 },
});

useEffect(() => {
 dispatch(saveDraftValues(formik.values)) 
}, [step])
```